# programmatically mocking a function

Tags: c, linux, embedded, linux-kernel

Is there any way to programmatically mock a function for a embedded c application, running on linux. In below example I want to mock main to call `someBlah` instead of `someFunc` in run-time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunc( void )
{
    printf("%s():%d\n",__func__,__LINE__);
}

void someBlah( void )
{
    printf("%s():%d\n",__func__,__LINE__);
}

int main(void)
{
    someFunc();
}
```

The program will be executing from ram in Linux so text segment should be modifiable. I know GDB works on some similar concept where breakpoints code locations are replaced by trap instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make some part of the text segment modifiable by an appropriate call to [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) and overwrite some code with your own (e.g. by generating machine code with libjit, GNU lightning, ... or manually).

But using function pointers is a cleaner way of doing that.

If the functions are inside a shared library, you could even overwrite its [Procedure Linkage Table](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker10.html) (see also the [ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), which depends upon the architecture - here is one for [ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html))

Comment: I am yet to try your approach, but it looks appropriate. So accepting your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just make a table of function pointers.

```
#define BLAH 0
#define FOO 1
void (*table_function[])(void) = {someBlah, someFoo};
```

If they all have the same interface and return type, you can just switch them by switching table entries.

Then you call a function by performing

```
table_function[BLAH]();
```

If you want to swap a function, just say

```
table_function[BLAH] = otherBlah;
```

Also: don't do this unless you are writing some kind of JIT-compiling environment or a VM, usually you don't need such constructs and if you need them you are probably having a bad architecture day.

Although if you're experienced in OO design you can design polymorphic constructs in C that way (ignore this if that doesn't make sense).

Comment: Or implementing virtual tables :)

Comment: I cant change the implementation in parent function in our case its "main()"

Comment: No my question has got nothing to do with VM / OO design, we are trying to come up with a platform unit testing, so the requirement is to mock but in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mocking frameworks for C.

At work, we've had some success with [cgreen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgreen/) but we did have to make changes to its internals.  Luckily, it's quite small, and so relatively easy to extend.  An alternative that looks good, but I haven't worked with, is a combination of [Unity](http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/unity-intro.html) and [CMock](http://throwtheswitch.org/white-papers/cmock-intro.html).

On the general topic of unit testing embedded C code, I highly recommend [Test Driven Development for Embedded C](http://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c).

Answer (score 0):

Another way I have done this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG

void someFunc( void )
{
#ifndef DEBUG
    printf("%s():%d\n",__func__,__LINE__);
#else
    printf("%s():%d\n",__func__,__LINE__);
#endif
}

int main(void) 
{
    someFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CMocka, there is an article about mocking on LWN: [Unit testing with mock objects in C](https://lwn.net/Articles/558106/)